# String concatenate Boolean value return True twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to concatenated values to a string.
Why is it that that my boolean value from bool_value is return Twice?

print example: 'ABCDE123','2021-03-06 12:28:45.264250',25.67,TrueTrue,2000

I expect it to return 'ABCDE123','2021-03-06 12:23:30.493241',25.67,True,2000

Thank you

```
EUI = 'ABCDE123'
datetime =  str(dt.now())
temperature = 25.67
bool_value = True
integer_value = 2000
col_names = ['EUI', 'datetime', 'temperature', 'bool', 'integer_value']
col_values = [EUI, datetime, temperature, bool_value, integer_value]

len_col = len(col_names)
if len_col > 0:
    col_names_str = ''
    col_values_str = ''
    for_count = 1
    
    for x in range(len_col):
        col_names_str += col_names[x]
        if isinstance(col_values[x], str) : col_values_str +=  f"'{col_values[x]}'"
        if isinstance(col_values[x], int) : col_values_str +=  str(col_values[x])
        if isinstance(col_values[x], float) : col_values_str +=  str(col_values[x])
        if isinstance(col_values[x], bool) : col_values_str += str(col_values[x])

        if for_count < len_col:
            col_names_str += ','
            col_values_str += ','

        for_count = for_count + 1

    print(col_names_str)
    print(col_values_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so you're adding it twice.

It looks like what you actually want to do would be simpler using `','.join` and `repr`:

```py
col_names_str = ','.join(col_names)
col_values_str = ','.join(repr(x) for x in col_values)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

1 and 0 represent True and False. as @kaya3 mentioned bool is a subclass of int, so  adding it twice.

```
x = 1
print(isinstance(x, int))

x = True
print(isinstance(x, int))

x = True
print(isinstance(x, bool))
```